# Error when inserting user with Enum role into PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, orm, mapping

I am encountering an issue when attempting to insert a new user with a role into my PostgreSQL database. I have a Spring Boot application where users are represented by a UserEntity class, and each user has a role defined by an enum called Role.

Here is a simplified version of my `UserEntity` class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String tel;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
    private Role role;
  }
```

The Role enum is defined as follows:

```
public enum Role {
    ADMIN,
    VENDEUR
}
```

When I try to save  new user with a role, I encounter the following error:

```
Internal Server Error",
  "trace": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [ERREUR: syntaxe en entrée invalide pour le type oid : « VENDEUR »] [insert into users (email,password,role,tel,username,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL [insert into users (email,password,role,tel,username,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)]
```

I have verified that the column type for role in my PostgreSQL database is VARCHAR. I have also ensured that I am using the correct enum value (Role.VENDEUR) when inserting the user.

What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I use **Spring boot** `3.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

I have identified an issue with Hibernate not updating Enum values in the database when using the property spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update. Initially, I did not specify `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` when defining the role field in the `UserEntity` class. This caused the enum values to be stored as oid instead of strings in the database, leading to errors.

To resolve the error, I had to take the following steps:

- Delete the existing database.
- Create a new empty database.
- Re-run the server with `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` definition for
  the role field.

This approach resolved the issue for me. However, it is worth noting that this solution is not ideal, as it involves deleting the entire database and starting over. It appears that there may be an issue with Hibernate's handling of `Enum` values when using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`.